# Not able to access JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm not able to access the JSON from my file. My JSON file content is:

```
    {
        "AuditQuestions": [{
            "categoryName": "General",
            "QuestionList": [{
                "quesId": "01",
                "type": "editText",
                "questText": "Inspected By",
                "answer": ""
            },

                {
                    "quesId": "02",
                    "type": "editText",
                    "questText": "This Audit Is For City:",
                    "answer": ""
                },

                {
                    "quesId": "03",
                    "type": "editText",
                    "questText": "This Audit Is For Property:",
                    "answer": ""
                },
    ]
    },

    {
                "categoryName": "Accessibility, Location and Security",

                "QuestionList": [{
                    "quesId": "17",
                    "type": "radio",
                    "questText": "Could you find the property easily with the address given",
                    "answer": ["Yes", "No"]
                },

                    {
                        "quesId": "18",
                        "type": "editText",
                        "questText": "Please suggest what we can add to the address to make it more locatable (eg: what landmark?)",
                        "answer": ""
                    },
    ]
    }
.
.
.
.
.
.
    }]
```

Each 'QuestionList' has like 10-15 sets, but I have skipped them for simplicity.

My code to access it is:

```
public void getQuestion(String page) {

        questionList = new ArrayList<QuestionList>();
        String category;
        String quesId ;
        String questionType ;
        String questionText;
        String answer;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(page);
            JSONArray jssArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("AuditQuestions");
            int jsonArrLength = jssArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildObj = jssArray.getJSONObject(i);
                category = jsonChildObj.getString("categoryName");
                quesId = jsonChildObj.getJSONObject("QuestionList").getString("quesId");
                questionType = jsonChildObj.getJSONObject("QuestionList").getString("type");
                questionText = jsonChildObj.getJSONObject("QuestionList").getString("questText");
                answer = jsonChildObj.getJSONObject("QuestionList").getString("answer");

                    QuestionList qList = new QuestionList();
                    qList.setQuesId(quesId);
                    qList.setQuesText(questionText);
                    qList.setQuesTypw(questionType);
                    qList.setAnswer(answer);
                    qList.setCategoryName(category);
                    questionList.add(qList);

                }

.
.
.
.
.
}
```

I tried to find if something was wrong with my code. But it looks fine to me.
Please help if there is  something wrong with the code I've used above. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That JSON is not valid (`}, ]`).

Comment: I'm trying to access the JSON from the local database in android which can be put in the XML layout dynamically. Just wanted to get help seeing if there is any problem with the code.

I apologise if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: Have you tried… running the code?

Comment: Yes, the code runs without any error or exception, but the contents of file don't appear in the output.

Comment: If you expect a code review, then post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead and delete this question. If there is a genuine problem with this code, then please describe the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Contento Why didn't you say so in the first place?! That type of information, preferably together with a [mcve], should be in the question.

Comment: @Contento its working code you have any other error . check my answer

Comment: I think the issue is with some other part of the code. Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildObj = jssArray.getJSONObject(i);
                category = jsonChildObj.getString("categoryName");

                JSONArray jsonArrayQueList = jsonChildObj.getJSONArray("QuestionList");

                for(int j = 0 ; j<jsonArrayQueList.length(); j++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectqueDetail = jsonArrayQueList.getJSONObject(j);

                    quesId = jsonObjectqueDetail.getString("quesId");
                    questionType = jsonObjectqueDetail.getString("type");
                    questionText = jsonObjectqueDetail.getString("questText");
                    answer = jsonObjectqueDetail.getString("answer");

                    QuestionList qList = new QuestionList();
                    qList.setQuesId(quesId);
                    qList.setQuesText(questionText);
                    qList.setQuesTypw(questionType);
                    qList.setAnswer(answer);
                    qList.setCategoryName(category);
                    questionList.add(qList);

                }


            }
```

Answer (score -1):

**First your json should like follow**

```
{
        "AuditQuestions": 
[
{
            "categoryName": "General",
            "QuestionList": [
{
                "quesId": "01",
                "type": "editText",
                "questText": "Inspected By",
                "answer": ""
            },

                {
                    "quesId": "02",
                    "type": "editText",
                    "questText": "This Audit Is For City:",
                    "answer": ""
                },

                {
                    "quesId": "03",
                    "type": "editText",
                    "questText": "This Audit Is For Property:",
                    "answer": ""
                }]

    },

    {
                "categoryName": "Accessibility, Location and Security",

                "QuestionList": [{
                    "quesId": "17",
                    "type": "radio",
                    "questText": "Could you find the property easily with the address given",
                    "answer": ["Yes", "No"]
                },

                    {
                        "quesId": "18",
                        "type": "editText",
                        "questText": "Please suggest what we can add to the address to make it more locatable (eg: what landmark?)",
                        "answer": ""
                    }]


}]
}
```

**Then parse like this. i have parse it and put your questions QuestionList object**

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(input);
            JSONArray jssArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("AuditQuestions");
            int jsonArrLength = jssArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildObj = jssArray.getJSONObject(i);
                category = jsonChildObj.getString("categoryName");

                JSONArray jssArray1 = jsonChildObj.getJSONArray("QuestionList");
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jssArray1.length(); i1++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildObj1 = jssArray1.getJSONObject(i1);
                    questionType = jsonChildObj1.getString("type");
                    questionText = jsonChildObj1.getString("questText");
                    answer = jsonChildObj1.getString("answer");
                    quesId = jsonChildObj1.getString("quesId");

                    QuestionList qList = new QuestionList();
                    qList.setQuesId(quesId);
                    qList.setQuesText(questionText);
                    qList.setQuesTypw(questionType);
                    qList.setAnswer(answer);
                    qList.setCategoryName(category);
                    questionList.add(qList);

                }

            }

        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I am getting all result dont know about you then

Answer (score -1):

First your json data which yo want to parse is wrong.

Try to format your json string and then parse,

Try to add your json data in a jsonviewer and change accordingly.

The jsonviewer link as follows:

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/